# PHP session management broken even though it works in 3 other environments

Tags: php, session

I have a large PHP app that's been working for YEARS, it worked in an `Apache/cPanel/Mysql` hosted local data center, it worked in `Docker` with the standard docker images, and in a few other places over the years.

Now, it appears that my `$_SESSION` variables aren't being preserved between page flips. It's not me doing it, I've thoroughly debugged the code and the `$_SESSION` variables are definitely not being preserved between page flips.

What is the problem here? Is there something in the `php.ini` I need to pay attention to? Right now I'm running in the `AWS` cloud with the standard `Bitnami` (`VMWare`) distribution which contains Apache and `MySql`, so it should be a pretty identical environment to what I was using before. The pages are being served, and `PHP` appears to be working fine (once I get inside the page it's all good). However all the `$_SESSION` variables are getting clobbered between page flips.

Is there another way to determine the current session ID? It looks like "something" is regenerating my session ID with every page flip. If I call `session_id()` as the very first line of code at the top of the page, I get a 0. Subsequently then, my logic says "gee, I have no session `ID`, I better go create one", and then it calls `session_start` and after that everything is fine, I can get into the page and everything works as it should "`while`" the page is being displayed.

I was expecting this to behave in exactly the same way as the previous incarnations of the app, but apparently there's something different somewhere, and I have no idea where to look. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has something changed recently in the environment? We don't have a lot to go on here.

Comment: Something changes the session ID with every page flip? Is your SSL Cert done? If the Session key is not staying, you have session problems, make sure to check the settings, like is_secure on your cookie -> must be on https ..etc.

Comment: Thank you Dxg125, looks like you're on the right track. The site broke when I installed the CloudFront certificate which uses https, and now PHP won't remember any sessions at all. There's another odd thing I noticed though, this PHP is returning session ID's in character form, whereas all the previous incarnations were numeric.